# New Distro 15.10 Wireless No Longer Works

Tags: networking, wireless, usb

I have TWO USB wireless network adapters, one is a REALTEK and one is an EDIMAX, both of them use the RTL8188CU chipset.
The used to work OOTB on previous versions of UBUNTU but now neither one of them will connect on 15.10.
Are there any USB Network adapters which work Right of the bat or can someone point me in the direction of a workaround?
Many thanks
Paul

Comment: The main ubuntu pages indicate that there is a specific driver available for these devices.  Have you looked over [this page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man4/urtwn.4freebsd.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to reference this page on help.ubuntu.com.

Provides information on troubleshooting wireless network.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html